# Training Yolov3-v4 with own dataset for real-time object detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, object-detection, yolo

I have a real-time problem which is aimed to detect 9 objects. As far as I understand, yolo has promising results on real-time object detection problems so I am searching good instructions to train a pre-trained yolo model with my custom "own" dataset.

I have my dataset and they are already labeled, also they have bounding box coordinates in .txt files in yolo format. However, it is a bit confusing to find a good instruction on the web about yolo custom dataset training for own object detection problem, since instructions are mostly using generic dataset such as COCO, PASCAL etc. or their instructions are not well enough to implement the object detection model on own dataset.

**TL;DR**
**My question is**, are there some handy instructions about implementing yolo object detection for own dataset? I am more looking for frameworks to implement yolo model rather than darknet C implementation since I am more familiar with python so it would be perfect if you could provide Pytorch or Tensorflow implementation.

It is more appraciated if you already implemented yolov3-v4 with your own dataset with the help of instructions you found on the web and you are willing to share those instructions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Back when I used yolov3 I trained on a custom dataset with the help of https://medium.com/@anirudh.s.chakravarthy/training-yolov3-on-your-custom-dataset-19a1abbdaf09

Comment: Thanks @AbdeslemSMAHI for sharing it but i am looking for an implementation of yolov3-v4 in Pytorch or Tensorflow frameworks.

Comment: There isn't much difference , only the command of training will change if you use either a Pytorch or a Tensorflow implementation.

Answer (score 1):

For training purpose I would highly recommend [AlexeyAB's repository](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects) as it's highly optimised for accuracy and speed, although it is also written in C. As far as testing and deployment is considered you have a lot of options:

- OpenCV's DNN Module: refer [this](https://pyimagesearch.com/2018/11/12/yolo-object-detection-with-opencv/) article.
- [Tensorflow Model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/vision/beta/projects/yolo)
- [Pytorch Model](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/PyTorch_YOLOv4)

Out of these OpenCV's DNN implementation is the fastest for testing/inference.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but I am more looking for "own" dataset training of Yolo implementations. Tensorflow model you shared seems to be in a development stage and pytorch model you pointed does not include own dataset implementations.

Comment: You can train model using AlexeyAB's repository on your own data(The repo is well documented and is easy to use for custom dataset training) and then when you have the model deploy it using OpenCV's DNN.